Sharepoint API - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
We have nextjs application deployed on the AWS. For user we provide opportynity to use OneDrive FilePicker (v.8).
When user just picked the file we call https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{fileId} endpoint to get file info.
On other page we also use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{fileId} to get @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl field and make a call to this url to download the file (that one is also starts from https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/).
The issue is that one of ours testers after some period of properly working functionality in one moment starts to get error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET without any addional details on each https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com request.
User is authorized with granted needed permissions to the drive.
Requests to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0 finish successfully as any request to other external API.
Could you help to figure out what is going wrong? Please!

You need way more information from the tester who's reporting the error. A large number of possible reasons could be behind net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. I've seen it being caused by overlapping wifi AP connection issues; antivirus issues, OS-level network config changes, DNS issues etc.
